# How to copy the recovered data from Photorec to an external HD

Tags: partitioning, data-recovery

I am on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS and while installing ubuntu i wiped my whole harddrive.By looking at threads on this forum and asking questions i was able to install testdisk and recover one of my partition fully.But one of my other drive showed bad partition structure and was not able to recover.However on Photorec i was able to see all those files.My question is how do i copy the files to my external harddrive from the photorec?Mine system HD is 500gb and it says not enough space.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely you haven't set the location to save the files to correctly - I seem to remember it defaults to an unfortunate place.

You need to select your mounted external hard drive at this step:
http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec_Step_By_Step#Select_where_recovered_files_should_be_written